# jQuery Ajax - delayed response behaves strangely

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't understand the data returned from jQuery AJAX requests if the response is delayed. I'm running the request every second and if the response is delayed for, let's say, 3 seconds, the success method of AJAX is called

- in Chrome Linux: four responses in one time every 3 or 4 seconds
- in Firefox Linux: one response every 3 or 4 seconds

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bcxh3hd/3/):

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateData();

    function updateData(){
        doRequest();
        setTimeout(updateData, 1000);
    }

    function doRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/js/',
            type : "GET",
            data: {
                js: "",
                delay: 3
            },
            success: function(retVal){
                $('#result').append(new Date() + '<br>');
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("Error in network (" + error.status + ")");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Can I force jQuery to run the success method for every response, not in any group and also to force it to run the request every second? Thanks!

Comment: Why `ready()` handler is inside `doRequest()`..?

Comment: Are you sure success callbacks are being omitted..? BTW, do you actually want to sent requests every 100ms (that'll be a performance hit, your script is slowing my browser) or do you want to send the next request once the previous one is finished..? I'd suggest something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9bcxh3hd/1/) instead.

Comment: @T J: ready fixed, sorry, wrong position. I'm running script every second, not 100ms and yes, I have to do it. It is update of online data chart.

Comment: hmm... If you're getting the response only after `2-3` seconds, then what's the use of running previous callbacks..? Those  contain outdated information anyway...

Comment: Nope. Data are calculated for three seconds (data represent packet per second on firewall). It is average of last three seconds. So, I need to show average of last three seconds every second. It is task, I can't move with it. I hope it is clear, because my english is not good. :)

Comment: From [JSFiddle api](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html): `Data has to be provided via POST`

Comment: Edited fiddle for GET requests, same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s all about the cache. http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/9bcxh3hd/4/ kills the cache.

A get request with identical parameters is normally gotten from the cache.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
updateData();

function updateData(){
    doRequest();
    setTimeout(updateData, 1000);
}

function doRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/js/',
        type : "GET",
        **cache:false,**
        data: {
            js: "",
            delay: 3
        },
        success: function(retVal){
            $('#result').append(new Date() + '<br>');
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("Error in network (" + error.status + ")");
        }
    });
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

Under `<head>`:

```
<script>
    var second_1=0;
    var second_2=0;
    var second_3;
</script>
```

In my humble point of view, you should use global variables to store `second_1`, `second_2` and then use the response data (as `second_3`).

So, next, use your response data (for the 3rd second) and get an average of those values. Get rid of the delay, and do something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    second_3=data; //whatever part of data it is you are using
    var my_average = (second_1 + second_2 + second_3)/3;
    second_1 = second_2; // 2nd second becomes first
    second_2 = second_3; // and 3rd second becomes second
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea, but it can't help me. There is no packet per second number on the firewall. We have to count packets for three seconds and then get number. So, nope, I can't do a math in JS.